# HTML5 Ad made with Google webdesigner to Doubleclick for publishers Small Business

Tags: google-dfp, advertisement-server

How do I publish a HTML5-Ad in Doubleclick for publishers Small Business? Seems like I need to insert click-macros. But were do I insert them if it´s based on script-event?

Answer (score 2):

Generally when you're uploading an HTML5 creative, there are multiple files you are generally dealing with (CSS, JS, images, etc - along with the actual HTML file). The procedure is generally as follows:

1) DFP requires your creative assets (images, scripts, CSS etc) to be uploaded individually (Alternatively, the CSS and Javascript can be added inline into the HTML5 code).

2) The source code of your HTML file must be added to the "Code snippet" area.

3) Next, every file path in your creative code needs to be replaced by DFP file macros, which upon ad serving will be replaced by the absolute path url. If any file is referenced within a CSS or Javascript file, it will need to be brought/surfaced to the "Code Snippet", otherwise they won't be replaced by the actual paths.
So if your original HTML source has an img tag like this:

```
<img src="product1.jpg"/>
```

You need to pre-upload product1.jpg into DFP and change that img src to reference the DFP name for this file using the macro.  Thus it may end up looking like this:

```
<img src="%%FILE:JPG1%%"/>
```

But if you are using SVG images, you cannot currently use the macro in this way.  You'll need to either host the SVG files externally and reference with a full path to them (ie: `<img src="http://someserver/file.svg">`) or you can paste the contents of the SVG file in-line.

BR,
Bablu Chakma